# Define CSV attribute dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

Below is a CSV importer. It's working perfectly, but I would to make it more robust by defining the row dynamically.

How do I substitute attribute "name" with attribute I defined earlier before the execution of CSV?

```
For example:- name: row[1] --> name: row[attribute]
```

The example above prompts an error stated "no implicit conversion of String into Integer", which is obviously true.

Below is the code.

```
import_attribute = import_dimension.import_attributes.first
attribute = import_attribute.name

CSV.foreach(Rails.root.join('tmp','uploads', csv_path), col_sep: import_source.csv_delimiter,
  row_sep: :auto, skip_blanks: true, headers: false) do |row|

    target.create company: self.import_source.company, code: row[0], name: row[1]
end
```

Comment: You can create a CSV column to attribute configuration list as a Hash in your application. But it will work only if: you have the header in CSVs you import? and Are header names unique and will not change from CSV to CSV?

Comment: For example: a header in one CSV: `Company Code, Company Name` and header in another CSV: `Code, Name` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hash that maps the attributes to their positions in the array.

```
positions = {code: 0, name: 1}
```

and then

```
target.create company: self.import_source.company, code: row[positions[:code]], name: row[positions[:name]]
```